# How can I have jQuery code further optimized?

Tags: jquery

I would like to see if my code below can still be optimized, resulting in lesser lines of code. My code retrieves the values from a multiselect field and assign them to hidden fields that will be passed to an integrated googlesheet. Thanks

```
 jQuery(".ff-btn-submit").click(function() {
        if(jQuery("input:radio[name=gift_choice]").is(":checked") ) {
            if (jQuery("input[name=gift_choice]:checked").val() == 'yes') {
                // Retrieve multi-select values
                var selectedValues = [];
                selectedValues = $('#ff_124_multi_select_gifts').val();
                
                // Set hidden input with the chosen gift.
                if (selectedValues.length > 0) {
                  jQuery("input[name=gift_1]").val(selectedValues[0]);
                  jQuery("input[name=gift_2]").val(selectedValues[1]);
                  jQuery("input[name=gift_3]").val(selectedValues[2]);
                  jQuery("input[name=gift_4]").val(selectedValues[3]);
                  jQuery("input[name=gift_5]").val(selectedValues[4]);
                  jQuery("input[name=gift_6]").val(selectedValues[5]);
                } 
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. The site standard is for the title to **simply state the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Yes, I agree and ensure to follow the standard going forward. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have few hints save jQuery in $ variable:

```javascript
(function($) {
   // your code
})(jQuery);
```

$ is common for jQuery and it's easier to read because it shorter.

Second and obvious is using loop to run calls in:

```javascript
    if (selectedValues.length > 0) {
       selectedValues.forEach(function(value, i) {
          var num = i + 1;
          $(`input[name=gift_${num}]`).val(value);
       });
    }
```

and further improvement is to move that into a function. So instead of comment:

```javascript
// Set hidden input with the chosen gift.
```

you can have:

```javascript
setHiddenInputs(selectedValues);


function setHiddenInputs(values) {
    values.forEach(function(value, i) {
        var num = i + 1;
        $(`input[name=gift_${num}]`).val(value);
    });
}
```

I would also merge those two lines:

```javascript
var selectedValues = [];
selectedValues = $('#ff_124_multi_select_gifts').val();
```

you assign array for no reason and then replace it with output of val() call:

```javascript
var selectedValues = $('#ff_124_multi_select_gifts').val();
```

also if selectedValues are gifts then you can use:

```javascript
var selectedGifts = $('#ff_124_multi_select_gifts').val();
setHiddenInputs(selectedGifts);
```

which is exactly what your comment try to say